# How do I create a standalone exe with AutoHotkey?

Tags: executable, autohotkey, keyboard-events

I have created a [script to remap the Windows Button to right-mouseclick](https://superuser.com/questions/743903/how-to-map-the-touchscreen-windows-button-to-right-mouseclick).

How can I create an executable AutoHotkey file that I can offer for download, that automatically runs only that script?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

Why not use [Ahk2exe](https://github.com/AutoHotkey/Ahk2Exe)? According to its docs, you can use it in three ways:

> 1. GUI Interface: Run the "Convert .ahk to .exe" item in the Start Menu.
> 2. Right-click: Within an open Explorer window, you can right-click any .ahk file and select "Compile Script" (only available if the script compiler option was chosen when AutoHotkey was installed). This creates an EXE file of the same base filename as the script, which appears after a short time in the same directory. Note: The EXE file is produced using the same custom icon, .bin file and use MPRESS setting that were last used by Method #1 above.
> 3. Command Line: The compiler can be run from the command line with the following parameters:
>
>    ```
>    Ahk2Exe.exe /in MyScript.ahk [/out MyScript.exe] [/icon MyIcon.ico] [/bin AutoHotkeySC.bin] [/mpress 0or1]
>    ```
>
> For example:
>
> ```
>     Ahk2Exe.exe /in "MyScript.ahk" /icon "MyIcon.ico"
> ```

Usage:

Parameters containing spaces should be enclosed in double quotes.
If the "out" file is omitted, the EXE will have the same base filename as the script itself.

Comment: Keep in mind that Ahk2exe will not exactly convert script to binary executable. The generated .exe file will contain plain script and AutoHotkey interpreter.

Comment: @vasili111 +1 also, that is because AutoHotkey is an interpreted language.

Comment: I tried to compile with /pass abcd@12345Ab
I get error: Password protection is not supported. How can I do?

Comment: Also see [Upcoming Ahk2Exe Changes (2019)](https://www.autohotkey.com/boards/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=65095).

Answer (score 2):

Just want to add that, quoting from [Convert a Script to an EXE (Ahk2Exe)](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Scripts.htm#ahk2exe):

> Once a script is compiled, it becomes a standalone executable; that is, AutoHotkey.exe is not required to run the script. The compilation process creates an executable file that contains the following: the AutoHotkey interpreter, the script, any files it [includes](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/_Include.htm), and any files it has incorporated via the [FileInstall](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/commands/FileInstall.htm) command. [v1.1.33+]: Additional files can be included using [compiler directives](https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/misc/Ahk2ExeDirectives.htm).